# mongoose nested array filter

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have a document form similar to this

```json
{
  "doc-id":2,
  "interfaces": [
    {
     
      "interface-role": "ON",
      "port-nb": 1
    },
    {
      
      "interface-role": "OFF",
      "port-nb": 2
    },
    {
      
      "interface-role": "ON",
      "port-nb": 3
    },
    {
      "interface-role": "OFF",
      "port-nb": 3
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to query and get specific document interfaces and also have the ability to filter ON and OFF and that's what I did try so far

```js
   const doc = await this.doc
        .findOne({
          'doc-id': docId,
          'interfaces["interface-role"]': interfaceRole, //ON or OFF
        })
        .select({ interfaces: 1, _id: 0 })
        .exec();
```

so the result that I want to have is getting interfaces if there's no filter for interfaces-role and if there's one get the interfaces filtered

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `$or` to do the conditional filtering with a `$filter`.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "doc-id": 2
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "interfaces": {
        "$filter": {
          "input": "$interfaces",
          "as": "i",
          "cond": {
            $or: [
              {
                $eq: [
                  null,
                  <interfaceRole>
                ]
              },
              {
                $eq: [
                  "$$i.interface-role",
                  <interfaceRole>
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/MW3-5WFzqps) when `interfaceRole` is not supplied.

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/qvQ-tS0ksNL) when `interfaceRole` is supplied.